# Linked server failed a connection

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Going to receive data by linked server in `MSSMS`.  Now I can connect to server by `Connect -> DB Engine`. By this type of connection all OK - can see all data. When I try to create linked server has Error

> OLE DB provider for linked server returned message "Login timeout expired".
>
> "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. …

This is the server description problem to which I want to connect, or it is restrictions on the access protocols or some thing else for the local server?

Comment: "Server is not found or not accessible" means that or your server is down, or you use incorrect server name, or it's your firewall

Comment: I can see this server and connect by any tools like query builder, but have problem to connect as  _linked sever_  to ecexute procedure

Comment: Your firewall can have exeptions for different programs. YOU can write server name incorrectly

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think it's a firewall and I do not have the ability to open it. It is necessary to think how  receive the data from other server by procedure by other ways, without using linked server

Comment: You can use SSIS to connect directly to another server and to load data into yours